# Parse Update Row in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
exports.updateProfile = function(req, res) {
    var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Profile);
    query.equalTo("username", req.body.username);
    query.first({
        success: function(Profile) {
            Profile.save(null, {
                success: function(profile) {
                    profile.set(req.body, { //It breaks here...
                        success: function(object) {
                            res.send({"error":"none"});
                        },
                        error: function (object, error) {
                            res.send({"error":"Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message});
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (object, error) {
                    res.send({"error":"Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message});
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            res.send({"error":"Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message});
        }
    });
}
```

However, neither the success nor error methods are called at the "It breaks here" line. Any ideas or better ways to update Parse rows using Node.js? Thanks.

Comment: Is the nesting deliberately introduced to demonstrate the bug? If not, you could probably do with some refactoring.

Comment: @Asad How could it be refactored?

Comment: Well, it looks to me like all of your error callbacks are identical, for a start. Write it at the top as a function named errorCallback or something, and refer to it each time. `function errorCallback() { ... }`, then later: `error: errorCallback`. Sorry I can't help with your actual problem, I'm not very familiar with Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.updateProfile = function(req, res) {
    var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Profile);
    query.equalTo("username", req.body.username);
    query.first().then(function(Profile){
        Profile.set("columnName", value);//value might be you are getting from req.body 
        Profile.save().then(function(saved){
            res.send({"error":"none"});
        }, function(error){
            res.send(error);
        });
    }, function(error){
        res.send(error);
    });
}
```

This might be the thing you are looking for. Try this approach hope it will help. You were saving an object that is not yet modified, That could be the reason why it is not coming to the call back method. Refactored the code to remove the invalid save call.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work or hit the error functions.

Comment: That's the problem, there's no error. It's not outputting anything.

Comment: use console.log(error); and go to cloud code and paste me the error. Or simply send the error to the client so that you can see it in response.

Comment: Check the server log from Parse dash you can see, This will be there

Comment: I don't see a place for server log.

Comment: Okay go to Parse.com login and select the project. Now select cloud code in that select the tab log and you are there

Comment: We don't use Cloud Code for our project, so it's all disabled. We only use the data browser.

Comment: Then how you are able to connect to the server logs won't be disabled you can still see them

Comment: It simply says "No logs to show yet". The connection is not an issue because all other functions are working.

Comment: left side you have two options info and error check any of these

Comment: Even I was wondering about the magic happening there ;) There will be an option to enable the server log check it otherwise it gonna effect the development so bad.